# Return at function from CoroutineScope

Tags: kotlin

I have something similar to the following code.

```
suspend fun foo() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // how to return at foo?
    }
    // more code here
}
```

How do I return at `foo`? When I do just plain old `return`, I get `'return' is not allowed here` and `return@withContext` suggested to me, but I don't want to call return on `withContext`, I want to call return on `foo`.

Comment: I'm not sure if i follow but how about just calling it outside the withContext lambda? You must have tried it already, but we don't know that. "tried this but raise this error"(provide code) and "tried this as well but cause this"(also provide) would sure help.

Comment: @Hiro I need to call it inside `withContext`.

Comment: could you elaborate more? If you want to return, surely you have some conditions in there, correct?

Comment: @Hiro Yep that is correct, "if something then return"

Comment: @Hiro What I've done for the moment is call `foo` from inside a `withContext`

Answer (score 1):

```
suspend fun foo() {
   return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext something
    }
}
```

Comment: I have code after `withContext` so I can't do that. Edited my question to include this info.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `return@foo` from inside `withContext`, so your only choice is to return some value from `withContext` and check it after and decide if you want to continue or return.

For example:

```
suspend fun foo() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Code that might return null or not
    }?.let {
        // More code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you're saying you want to do is *conditionally* return early from `foo()` based on some branch of code in your `withContext` block.

Since `withContext` is not an inline function, it can only return from itself. So you can either do this:

```
suspend fun foo() {
    var shouldContinue = true
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //some code
        if (something) { // condition under which you want to return early
            shouldContinue = false
            return@withContext
        }
        // some more code
    }
    if (!shouldContinue) {
        return
    }
    // more code here
}
```

Or make your `withContext` return a Boolean from all its branches to determine whether to continue on:

```
suspend fun foo() {
    val shouldContinue = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //some code
        if (something) { // condition under which you want to return early
            return@withContext false
        }
        // some more code
        true // implicit return
    }
    if (!shouldContinue) {
        return
    }
    // more code here
}
```

Or if you are using it to produce some result that you will do something with, then you can return null for the cases where it can exit early and return nothing:

```
suspend fun foo() {
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //some code
        if (something) { // condition under which you want to return early
            return@withContext null
        }
        // some more code
        yourResult
    }
    result ?: return // no result, return early
    // do something with non-null result
}
```